# How to convert an Electrum 12 word seed to a private key?

Tags: electrum, seed

How can I convert an Electrum 12 word seed to a private key?

I heard Electrum has a special type of algorithm where the 12 word seed can't be used on other wallet software; is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't seen a tool, that can do so. 
Electrum has a BIP39 based system, with some custom extension. Look for BIP39 and Electrum, this appeared already in bitcoin stackexchange. From (somewhere) there I also got the compatibility list:

> https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=584F122BA17116EE!313&app=Excel

Internally in Electrum wallet, you can export via menu "Wallet" -> "PrivKeys" -> "Export".

Comment: can I extract private key even when Electrum network is offline?

Answer (score 0):

If you export the PrivKeys, you get a sheet with all transactions, you need this.

Right-click in your Electrum in History on a transaction you received BTC on, then click details.

Then you have to look for the corresponding transaction in the sheet you downloaded, and look for the corresponding PrivKey.

Go to your Coinomi and go to BTGold wallet, select sweep wallet, here you can put in your PrivKey, and you will get the BTGold of that previous BTC transaction.

If you have more transactions BTC in your electrum, you need to input more PrivKeys in Coinomi, but they get counted together.