# Python: Why the addresses and keys generated by pywallet and bip32utils using the same 12 mnemonic words don't match?

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, address-generation, python, mnemonic-seed

I tried to generate wallets by using `pywallet` and `bip32utils` (Python). But I noted that the addresses/keys of the 2 wallets, namely `wallet_pywallet` and `wallet_bip39` don't match with each other.

I noted that the addresses/keys of `wallet_bip39` match with Exodus, but `wallet_pywallet` doesn't. We have been using `pywallet` for such a long time so I believe `wallet_pywallet` should be correct as well. Why is there such a discrepancy?

Below is the code, while the code for `wallet_bip39` is obtained from [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76655/how-to-generate-public-and-private-key-pairs-from-the-12-seed-words-in-python).

```
from pywallet import wallet
import binascii
import mnemonic
import bip32utils

def bip39(mnemonic_words):
    mobj = mnemonic.Mnemonic("english")
    seed = mobj.to_seed(mnemonic_words)

    bip32_root_key_obj = bip32utils.BIP32Key.fromEntropy(seed)
    bip32_child_key_obj = bip32_root_key_obj.ChildKey(
        44 + bip32utils.BIP32_HARDEN
    ).ChildKey(
        0 + bip32utils.BIP32_HARDEN
    ).ChildKey(
        0 + bip32utils.BIP32_HARDEN
    ).ChildKey(0).ChildKey(0)

    return {
        'mnemonic_words': mnemonic_words,
        'addr': bip32_child_key_obj.Address(),
        'publickey': binascii.hexlify(bip32_child_key_obj.PublicKey()).decode(),
        'privatekey': bip32_child_key_obj.WalletImportFormat(),
        'coin': 'BTC'
    }


mnemonic_words = wallet.generate_mnemonic()
    
wallet_pywallet = wallet.create_wallet(network="BTC", seed=mnemonic_words, children=0)
wallet_bip39 = bip39(mnemonic_words)
    
print(wallet_pywallet)
print()
print(wallet_bip39)
```

Answer (score 1):

Derivation paths.

wallet_bip39 is using m/44'/0'/0' while (if I looked at the right pywallet code) pywallet is using m/0'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to change the bip39()'s code to `bip32_child_key_obj = bip32_root_key_obj.ChildKey(0 + bip32utils.BIP32_HARDEN).ChildKey(0).ChildKey(0)`, but the keys/addresses of the two wallets still don't match with each other.